# Brute Force Regex String Match

Tags: python, regex

After much struggle I got this program to work, at least in the few test cases that I have tested it for.  It is a challenge i got from CodeWars and the task is to make a program that takes an input string (in order, or scrambled) and returns a boolean whether that input is made of a repeating substring.

My approach is to use itertools.permutations to list out all the possible strings that can be made from the given string input and then use a regex to match up against every single one of them.  Guaranteed to work, but also exponential complexity, which lead to a memory error on my wussy Intel i5 w/ 8gigs with an input of only 3 unique characters of len() == 12.

There must be a more efficient way to run this (within Python preferably, doing it in Pypy/ C extension is outside the scope of this assignment )

Enough preamble, here is my code:

```
def has_subpattern(string):
'''input: a string. Output: boolean: whether the input str is made of a
   smaller repeating substring. '''

import re
from itertools import permutations

if len(string) <= 1:
    return False

# check if the input has a repeating subpattern (in case it's not    scrambled)
if bool( re.match(r'(.+?)\1+$', string)) == True:
    return True

# create a set of the permutation of a string ( to remove duplicates)
perms = set([''.join(p) for p in permutations(string)])

pattern = re.compile(r'(.+?)\1+$')


print('# of permutations: ', len(perms))
print(perms)

# iterate through the list of permutations, checking if any has  #subpattern
for perm in perms:
    if bool((re.match(pattern, perm))) == True:
        print((re.match(pattern, perm)), perm)
        return True
return False
```

string = "123a213a321a"
print(has_subpattern(string))

Any suggestions on directions to go on this to reduce the run time?  I am a newb and totally nonplussed.

Comment: examples of test cases:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python for the counter approach in dave's post is:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(string)
print(set(c.most_common().values()) == 1)
```

Idea is to count all charachters, then check that the counts are all the same by getting a set of the values in the counter. If there is only one number in the set, all chars have the same count, and are scrambled substrings.

Comment: That does seem immensely more efficient than the way I had approached the problem.  Thanks !

Comment: does that make sense with the spec? from your description it is not clear if a case like '12312311' would return True, since the string is made of '1111', '22', '33' which are all repeating. If that is the case, use the same strategy, just check that all values in counter are greater than 1... upvote or accept if that works. cheers

Comment: examples of strings that pass or don't pass:
#    has_subpattern("a") == False #no repeated shorter sub-pattern, just one character
#    has_subpattern("aaaa") == True #just one character repeated
#    has_subpattern("abcd") == False #no repetitions
#    has_subpattern("babababababababa") == True #repeated "ba"
#    has_subpattern("bbabbaaabbaaaabb") == True #same as above, just shuffled
#

Answer (score 0):

I think you are approaching it wrong.  If it can be scrambled, you really only need to check if the count of each character is the same.  In javascript, you could do:

```js
function isRepeating(str) {
  var characters = str.split('');
  if (characters.length < 2) { return false; }
  var characterCounts = characters.reduce(function(carry, char) {
      carry[char] = carry[char] ? carry[char] + 1 : 1;
      return carry;
  }, {});
  var counts = Object.values(characterCounts);
  return !counts.some(c => c !== counts[0]);
}

console.log(isRepeating("123a123a321a")); // true
console.log(isRepeating("hello"));        // false
console.log(isRepeating("racecar"));      // false
console.log(isRepeating("raceecar"));     // true
```

For python, just follow the same approach - count the number of times each character appears, see if each character has the same count.

Answer (score 0):

After dicking around with counters a bit with the suggestions from the forum I created a solution that uses counters and is orders of magnitude less expensive than brute forcing all permutations against a regex:

here's what I gots:

```
def has_subpattern(string):
    ''' input: a string, output: boolean, whether the input is composed of a
        repeating substring '''
    from collections import Counter
```

`c = Counter(string)
if 1 in c.values():
    return False

return len(set(c.values())) == 1`